# Handle exception in haskell

Tags: list, exception, haskell

I write the following code:

```
give :: [b] -> Int -> b
give list index = list !! index
```

Now I want to add, if the there is no item at point index, it should show: "No item at that position!"

```
[1..10] `give` 10
No item at that position!
```

How can I add this in haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really. You can throw exceptions from pure code but you can only catch exceptions in `IO`.

You could either reimplement `!!` in `give` to throw an exception more to your liking or just opt for saner error handling, like `Either` or `Maybe`.

An example of handling errors with `Either` might be

```
data OutOfRange = OutOfRange Int

give :: [a] -> Int -> Either OutOfRange a
give xs i | length xs > i = Right $ xs !! i
          | otherwise     = Left (OutOfRange i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the return type in an `Either` monad like this:

```
give :: [b] -> Int -> Either String b
give [] _ = Left "No item at that position!"
give (x:xs) index | index == 0 = Right x
                  | otherwise  = give xs $ index - 1
```

`Either` is a data constructor whose declaration could theoretically look like this:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

`Right` and `Left` are value constructors for the different types that may be used, in our case, `b` and `String`.

This function returns `Either` a `String` or a `b` depending on whether or not the indexing succeeded. It uses pattern matching to fail when indexing into an empty list and uses recursion to eventually emulate `!!`. Note that due to the strictness of Haskell's type system, you cannot use this result as it were simply of type `b`: you must explicitly handle the possibility of it being a String. Here is an example:

```
case (give [1..10] 10) of
    (Left s)  -> putStrLn $ "Error" ++ s                                 --String case
    (Right i) -> putStrLn $ "The value you requested is " ++ show $ i    --Int case
```

Using `Either` and `Maybe` is generally a better idea than signaling errors because it allows your code to gracefully handle error conditions within the Haskell type system with simple pattern matching.